# Como retirar a linha que separa as colunas em uma tabela html?

Tags: html5, css3, tabela-html

Gostaria de saber como posso retirar a linha que separa as colunas desta tabela.

```css
table {
    font-family: url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf');
    border-collapse: collapse;   
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 500px;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #CACFD2;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Loja</th>
      <th>Faturamento</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Loja 01</td>
      <td>R$ 21.362,17</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Loja 02</td>
      <td>R$ 11.238,21</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Loja 03</td>
      <td>R$ 19.598,95</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Loja 04</td>
      <td>R$ 35.625,12</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Loja 05</td>
      <td>R$ 10.854,74</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer seria assim, coloquei a cor transparente na borda direita de todas as primeiras `td`

```css
table {
    font-family: url('../fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf');
    border-collapse: collapse;   
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 500px;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #CACFD2;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
td:first-of-type {
    border-right-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
    <table>
       <tr>
          <th>Loja</th>
          <th>Faturamento</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Loja 01</td>
          <td>R$ 21.362,17</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Loja 02</td>
          <td>R$ 11.238,21</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Loja 03</td>
          <td>R$ 19.598,95</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Loja 04</td>
          <td>R$ 35.625,12</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Loja 05</td>
          <td>R$ 10.854,74</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Valeu Hugo, isso mesmo cara.

Comment: @LeAndrade tranquilo jovem, pode ser que edita outro jeito, eu usei esse pq se eu tirar a linha vai ficar 1px desalinhado entende